# Как в линукс минт сделать так, чтобы программа запускалась при щелчке мышью?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-mint

Как запускать программу, написанную на g++ в линукс минт щелчком мыши, и как сделать, чтобы она так запускалась и при переносе на другой компьютер?

Comment: Программа g++? Вы не ошиблись?

Comment: а почему вы решили, что она не запускается?

Comment: @isnullxbh ошибся)я имел ввиду программу написанную на g++

Comment: @neo, стало ещё менее понятно: 1. не описано, что вы получаете сейчас и чего ожидаете. 2. как вообще можно «что-нибудь написать на программе *g++*»???

Comment: Кажись ТС имеет ввиду: либо ярлык, либо ассоциацию с расширением(как в винде, двойной щелчок по файлу открывает/запускает его в связанной программе). Такое компилятор не делает и не должен. В Ubuntu ярлык - это файл appname.desktop со спец-содержанием. Если программу, при переносе, копировать в туже директорию, к примеру /opt, ярлык должен работать. На mint скорей всего чтото подобное. Ну а в целом читайте мануал по интересующей ОС.

Answer (score 2):

программа *g++* — это [*компилятор*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80).

всё, что она может сделать при «запуске» (без указания как минимум файла с исходным текстом, который надо скомпилировать) — это написать в *stderr* сообщение об ошибке:

> g++: fatal error: no input files
>   compilation terminated.

---

вероятно, вы спутали *компилятор* с [*ide*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8), и ожидаете, что при запуске программа *g++* должна «нарисовать» какое-то окно с какими-то кнопками и прочими элементами графического интерфейса. увы, такая функциональность не заложена в данную программу её разработчиками.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли - я имел ввиду программу, написанную на g++